# ANSI Encoding implementation for Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, encoding, utf-8, codepages

I need Encoding implementation of some codepage in my Silverlight app. Particularly I need to read non-Engligh file names from zip-archive (being opened [Application.GetResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994%28VS.95%29.aspx)).

Silverlight contains only Unicode encodings (Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode). Encoding.GetEncoding throws exception for other encoding names.

But I need Encoding class implementation for some ANSI codepage (866 particularly). On desktop I'd get it via Encoding.GetEncoding(866).

Where can I get the simplest implementation?

p.s. I understand that the question hardly relates Silverlight, but without mentioning it I'll be suggested to use Encoding.GetEncoding I guess..

Comment: @Bala R: thanks! It's turned to be pretty easy. I wish you answered as "answer" not comment.

Comment: What in the world does “ANSI” mean?

Comment: @tchrist That means "ANSI code pages" or "Windows code pages". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_866 you can build a map and convert your stuff to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bala_R, i get 866 codepage and write:

```
    private byte[] translateInto866(string fileName)
    {
        const byte startCode1 = 128;        // А, 0410
        const byte startCode2 = 224;        // р, 0440

        var result = new byte[fileName.Length];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (char c in fileName)
        {
            if (c >= 'А' && c <= 'п')
            {
                result[i] = (byte)(((byte)(c - 'А')) + startCode1);
            }
            else if (c > 'п' && c <= 'я')
            {
                result[i] = (byte)(((byte)(c - 'р')) + startCode2);
            }
            else
            {
                result[i] = (byte) c;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Now we only need to understand what codepage was used to encode file name. We have its unicode representation in manifest and a representation in some encoding inside zip. It should be not very hard to find appropriate encoding. But in my case I just know that if it's not utf8 then it's 866.